# Command confluent local services start gives an error : Starting ZooKeeper Error: ZooKeeper failed to start

Tags: confluent-platform

I'm trying to run this command : `confluent local services start`

I don't know why each time it gives me an error before passing to the next step. So I had to run it again over and over until it passes all the steps.

what is the reason for the error and how to solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the log files to inspect any errors that would be happening.

But, it's possible the services are having a race condition. Schema Registry requires Kafka, REST Proxy and Connect require the Schema Registry... Maybe they are not waiting for the previous components to start.

Or maybe your machine does not have enough resources to start all services. E.g. I believe at least 6GB of RAM are necessary. If you have 8GB on the machine, and Chrome and lots of other services are running, for example, then you wouldn't have 6GB readily available.